# How to access individual elements in an array if the array is stored as a value in a Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm new to coding and this is my first post!

I have created a dictionary in Swift where each individual value is an array.

Ex

1: [0.0443, 0.220832, 0.526799, 0.72147, 0.646954,0.511456,1.00405]

What I need to do is to access the value and store into a different array for data manipulation.

I am having trouble doing this because swift is viewing the array as a single object.

ex. dict[1]!.count will print 1 not 7 (ie. the 7 values)

Is there a way to do this - meaning to get swift to store the value as an array of Doubles?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `type(of: dict)`?

Comment: [Int : NSArray]

Comment: What is `type(of: dict[1]!)`?  How are you initializing this dictionary?

Comment: in a Class as  var indexed: [Int: NSArray] = [ : ]

Comment: init (indexed: [Int: NSArray] = [ : ])

Comment: Where are the values coming from?

Comment: an array of doubles - data from the accelerometer from apple watch.  I have the watch oscillating on a spring and I have set up an algorithm that determines if the watch is above or below the z-axis.  So it is sorting whether it is the spring is compressed or in recoil.  A compression would be a + force and I need to store all the compressions and recoils individually.

Comment: How about making your `dict` `[Int: [Double]]` instead?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you shared some code with us. but to access a dictionary of arrays you can do something like this :

```
let array1 = ["a", "b" , "c"]
let array2 : [Float] = [1.2,2.8,3.4]
let dictionary : Dictionary<String, Any> = ["array1" : array1, "array2" :array2]

var arrayFromDictionary = dictionary["array1"] as! [String]
var array2FromDictionary = dictionary["array2"] as! [Float]

print(arrayFromDictionary[1])
print(array2FromDictionary[2])
```

the first print call  will print out "b" since it is the second member of the array1.

the second print call will print out 3.4 since it is the third member of array2.

does this answer your question ?

Comment: The problem is because I do not know when the spring will stop oscillating or if I want to stop the spring prematurely, there is no way of me knowing how many arrays I would need.  I thought a dictionary would make sense because I can just add as many as I want.

Comment: why not use a while loop and an array to store the values ? for example a pseudocode would be while sprinIsOscillating == true {array.append(value)}

Comment: I was also thinking of a 2D array, it might serve the same purpose.

Comment: The issue is I need all the compression and recoil values stored separately to graph and do other calculations.

Comment: Problem solved!  I changed my initialization from `indexed: [Int: NSArray] = [ : ]` to `var indexed: [Int: [Double]] = [ : ]`. Thanks all!  Don't know why I used NSArray, found it on another thread somewhere without understanding why!